# concatenating content of one file with another sequentially

Tags: linux, bash, shell, for-loop, cat

i have two sets of text files in a directory with extension `.ASC` and `.txt` (`1.ASC, 2.ASC, 3.ASC, 4.ASC....1000.ASC and 1.txt, 2.txt, 3.txt, 4.txt....1000.txt`).

I just want to concatenate `*.ASC` file with `*.txt` file and want to save it to different named files like `output_*.txt`

for example ( i want to concatenate `1.ASC` with `1.txt` and output is `output_1.txt`, similarly concatenate `2.ASC` with `2.txt` and output is `output_2.txt.....`)

I tried the below script

```
#!/bin/sh

for file1 in *.ASC
do
for file2 in *.txt
do
cat file1 file2 > output_$1
done
done
```

But the written script does not give the expected output.please suggest a better solution for the same.Thanks.

Comment: You just need one for loop over the index [1...1000].

Comment: Or just loop over `*.ASC` and then replace `.ASC` with `.txt` to get the name of the other corresponding file.

Comment: This should work: 
`for f in {1..1000}; do cat $f.ASC $f.txt > output_$f.txt; done`